# How can I debug a REST post request?

Tags: java, rest, post

I currently do have an issue developing a REST based application. As is usually help myself out using google, this time a little support would be very helpful.

I do send a REST post request that obviously does not match the method signature. Now I would like to debug the request I send. How can I fetch the sent request to inspect the data?

What I do? On the client side the method (this is not production level code btw.):

```
public boolean send() {
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().build();
    WebTarget target = client.target(
            "http://localhost:8080/backend_war_exploded/user/register"
    );

    // this = class Registration 
    Entity entity = Entity.entity(this, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    try {
        Registration registration = target
                .request()
                .post(
                        entity,
                        Registration.class
                );
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And on the server side:

```
@RequestMapping(
        value = "/register",
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        headers = "Accept=application/json",
        produces = "application/json"
)
public ResponseEntity<SystemUser> create(
        @RequestBody SystemUser body
) {
    ResponseEntity<SystemUser> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(
        systemUserService.create(body), HttpStatus.CREATED
    );
    return responseEntity;
}
```

In my log file, I end up with:

```
ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-30) UT005023: Exception handling request to 
/backend_war_exploded/user/register: 
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; 
nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
org.springframework.core.MethodParameter.getContainingClass()Ljava/lang/Class;
```

I do have some working GET requests, so the setup generally works. I hope I could provide all necessary but not too much code. If any information is missing, please let me know and I will add it. Helpful would be to either tell me, what I did understand wrong with the REST implementation, or to tell me, how I can find out what I understood wrong.

edit:
Alright, thanks to Jk1, I found I had duplicate libraries, which I fixed as described in [1]. Now I run into a BadRequestException, so I still would like to debug my REST service request. Any idea, on how I can debug this?

[1] [spring-data-jpa 1.6 requires spring framework 3 libraries, is that true, or what did I miss?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24493119/spring-data-jpa-1-6-requires-spring-framework-3-libraries-is-that-true-or-what/24495425#24495425)

Comment: It looks like you have incopartible spring jars or duplicates in the classpath

Comment: Only the endpoint runs with spring. I will check for duplicates now.