# spring-data-jpa 1.6 requires spring framework 3 libraries, is that true, or what did I miss?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-data-jpa

coming from a different issue, I saw that my Spring libraries are a kind of mixed up.

I have Spring-4.0.5 libraries (yes, I want them), and Spring 3.2.9-libraries, which are obviously given as spring-data-jpa-1.6 dependency through maven. Spring-data-jpa 1.4 seems not to pull the the spring 3 libraries, but I would absolutely prefer to work with the current 1.6.

Maven:

```
<properties>
    <org.springframework.version>4.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
[...]
```

Can anybody confirm this, or am I simply doing anything completely wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Manuel Jordan, I had to manually exclude the dependencies, so here is the full maven code for this dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to dexBerlins answers would be to use the <dependencyManagement> element. The advantage of this is that when you use it, *any* transitive dependency for the groupid and artifactid will be ignored and use the version you specify in the  element. Basically a global override:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Documentation -> http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies

Comment: I have this dependency in my pom.xml, but spring-data-jpa pulled spring-xyz-3.2.9 beside. So I had issues with a mix up of some libraries (3.2.9 & 4.0.5 of spring-xyz). That is why I discovered this issue.

Comment: Hi dexBerlin, sorry only half the solution(Was going from faded memory) I've updated the original post

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation, just **override** the spring-modules explicitly and the old references gone. For example.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

We must assume Spring Data (the next new release) should references a new Spring Framework release.